# How to get my header to repeat across the page on my tumblr blog?

Tags: html, header, blogs, repeat, tumblr

Ok, here is my blog:

http://thestorywithnoending.tumblr.com/

how can i get the top image (the header with the head/airplanes) to repeat over and over, so that the whole top will that image... right now its just one big image, but how can i adjust the code so that the image repeats?

Please test out the code, once youve thought of a way to fix it,

thank you so much! Whoever figures it out is awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

use a `#header div` above the `#left` div you are using now.

```
<div id="header">
   <!-- content -->
</div>
```

And then you can use CSS similar to the following (you'll have to set the height as appropriate:

```
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;

}

#left     
{ width:100%; 
height:100px; 
margin:0px; 
background-color:#FFF; 
background-image:url('http://i52.tinypic.com/15yxa40.png'); 
background-repeat:repeat-x; 
}
```

Comment: This didn't work.... could you try testing it out yourself? Because i was not able to get it to work, perhaps i followed your instructions incorrectly. When i did what you said, my frame disapeared, and the image no longer stayed in place.

Comment: could you be more specific, or try something else?  Thank you very much for your help so far.

Comment: Your HTML is all messed up. You have `<div>` elements in the header, and style in the body. Take a look at the code cleaned up and see if that doesn't work. http://pastebin.com/UKxm8qQT